# HTML - How to only load filtered images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to create an image filter for my webpage. I used the following code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
// Declare variables
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
input = document.getElementById('myInput');
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("searchColumns");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName('figure');
if (filter==""){
  li[i].style.display = "none";
}
else{
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("figcaption")[0];
      if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "inline-block";
      } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
 }  }
}
</script>
```

But the problem is that I have 200+ images there loading on startup, which takes a while. Is there a way to prevent them from loading until they appear on the filter?

Comment: if you add just the urls of the images to an array, you can create Image objects and add them to the list once there is a filter.

Comment: @A.Zaima could I use document.createElement()?

Comment: yes you can. So use the filter function to filter through the array of urls, then a for loop to go through your new array creating image elements for each url. This way you only load what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
function filterSearch() {
    var query = document.getElementById('myInput').value.toUpperCase(),
    ul = document.getElementById("searchColumns"),
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('figure');
    if (query == "") {
        ul.style.display = "none";
    }
    else for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        var a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("figcaption")[0];
        if (a.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(query) !== -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "inline-block";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the same thing, it works as a filter but it still loads the images that are not being shown

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @A.Zaima, I found a solution. I created an array with all the image links and another one with all the image names and wrote the following code:

```
var input, filter, a, i;
input = document.getElementById('myInput');
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
if (filter!=""){
  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      a = names[i];
      if (a.substring(0, filter.length)==filter) {
          var figure = document.createElement("FIGURE");
          var img = document.createElement("IMG");
          var figcaption = document.createElement("FIGCAPTION");
          var textnode = document.createTextNode(names[i]);
          figcaption.appendChild(textnode);
          img.src = links[i];
          document.getElementById("searchColumns").appendChild(figure);
          figure.appendChild(img);
          figure.appendChild(figcaption);
      }
    }
  }
}
```